# Filtering layer symbology with arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I'm using arcmap 10.1 and have one shp with many polygons with different typeID. I want to make a serie of maps showing each typeID on an individual map. Since I have many typeIDs I want to use arcpy. And here is the problem. I don't know which arcpy function to use to select only one typeID and remove all the others; and then repeat this step for all IDs.

SOLUTION:
Here is my code after I fixed it. Now it works:)

```
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

def getValueList (inputTable, field):
    values = set()
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inputTable)
    for row in rows:
            values.add(row.getValue(field))
    return sorted(values)

list=getValueList('my_shp_file', 'typeID')
lyr=arcpy.mapping.Layer('my_shp_file')
where_clause='"typeID"='

for type in list:
    lyr.definitionQuery=where_clause+str(type)  
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, "C:\\my_location\\"+str(type)+".jpg")
```

Thanks for suggestions!
Rok

Comment: If you have a layer file in your mxd pointing to your shapefile you can get to it's definition query and set it to be typeID="value" and then save.  I'm not sure how set() works but you'll probably want to ensure your list is unique.  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000008000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000) object do something like:

```
where_clause = "'" + my_field + " = " + typeID + "'"
if yourLayer.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
    yourLayer.definitionQuery = where_clause
```

It works great!